# List Iterator Not Iterating Over All Elements

Tags: c++, list, iterator, listiterator

I have a TreeVertex class:

```
// TreeVertex.h
#ifndef __TREEVERTEX__
#define __TREEVERTEX__

#include <list>

using namespace std;

class TreeVertex {
public:
    TreeVertex(list<int>, TreeVertex* = NULL);
    list<int> getItemset();
private:
    list<int> Itemset;

    TreeVertex * Parent;
    TreeVertex * LeftChild;
    TreeVertex * RightSibling;
};

#endif // __TREEVERTEX__

// TreeVertex.cpp

#include "TreeVertex.h"

TreeVertex::TreeVertex(list<int> Itemset, TreeVertex* Parent) : Itemset(Itemset),     Parent(Parent), LeftChild(NULL),
    RightSibling(NULL) { }

list<int>
TreeVertex::getItemset() {
    return Itemset;
}
```

And a main function like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TreeVertex.h"

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, const char ** const argv)
{    
    list<int> tmpList1;
    tmpList1.push_back(1);

    TreeVertex * tmpTreeVert1 = new TreeVertex(tmpList1);

    list<int> tmpList2;
    tmpList2.push_back(2);

    TreeVertex * tmpTreeVert2 = new TreeVertex(tmpList2);

    list<int> newVertItemset;

    newVertItemset.push_back(tmpTreeVert1->getItemset().front());
    newVertItemset.push_back(tmpTreeVert2->getItemset().front());

    cout << newVertItemset.front() << " " << newVertItemset.back() << endl;

    TreeVertex * newTreeVert = new TreeVertex(newVertItemset);

    cout << newTreeVert->getItemset().front() << " " << newTreeVert->getItemset().back() << endl;

    for (list<int>::iterator it = newTreeVert->getItemset().begin(); it != newTreeVert->getItemset().end(); ++it) {
        cout << (*it) << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << newTreeVert->getItemset().size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this:

1 2

1 2

2

2

The next to the last output (the first single "2"), should be "1 2" just like the others.

Any ideas why the iterator is not going over the first element?

Thanks.

Comment: Do not use `__TREEVERTEX__` as an include guard, names that begin with double underscore are reserved to the implementation. A better header guard would be simply `TREEVERTEX_H`.  Why do you create `TreeVertex` objects on the heap?  If you do create them on the heap, you must remember to `delete` them!

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that. For this example, you are right: I do not need to create the objects on the heap. In the real code, I need pointers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with this:

```
list<int>
TreeVertex::getItemset() {
    return Itemset;
}
```

Everytime you call this function, it returns a *copy* of the object, which means the following  loop should not work:

```
for (list<int>::iterator it = newTreeVert->getItemset().begin(); 
                         it != newTreeVert->getItemset().end(); ++it) {
```

as it compares iterators from two different objects. A solution is to return *reference* as:

```
list<int> &   //<--- return reference, not copy
TreeVertex::getItemset() {
    return Itemset;
}
```

But a better solution is to remove `getItemset` altogether and instead of that, add `begin()` and `end()` member functions as:

```
//define these typedefs first in the public section
typedef list<int>::iterator iterator;
typedef list<int>::const_iterator const_iterator;  

iterator begin() { return itemSet.begin(); }
iterator end() { return itemSet.end(); }
```

and then write the `for` loop as:

```
for(TreeVertex::iterator it = newTreeVert->begin(); 
                         it != newTreeVert->end(); ++it) {
```

If you can use C++11, then you should add these:

```
//note : the function names start with `c`
const_iterator cbegin() const { return itemSet.cbegin(); }
const_iterator cend() const { return itemSet.cend(); }
```

Or, if you use C++03 (and cannot use C++11), then add these:

```
const_iterator begin() const { return itemSet.begin(); }
const_iterator end() const { return itemSet.end(); }
```